# java.lang.StackOverflowError by setImageResource

Tags: java, android

My android app get a crash when init a tabhost.But the crash log from users is rather strange!

Mostly of the crash came from android 2.3.x, on android 4.x it works well.

I can see when I involke "setImageResource"  the code ran into a infinate  recursion, but I can't understand why.
code:

```
    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);   
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageResource(drawableId);  // crashed
```

```
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable$StateListState.<init>(StateListDrawable.java:257)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.<init>(StateListDrawable.java:303)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.<init>(StateListDrawable.java:70)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1712)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:590)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1712)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:590)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1712)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:590)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1712)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:590)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1712)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:590)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1712)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:590)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1712)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:590)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1712)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:590)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1712)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:590)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1712)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:590)
at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:564)
at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:280)
at com.thankcreate.care.MainActivity.addTab(MainActivity.java:95)
at com.thankcreate.care.MainActivity.setTabs(MainActivity.java:78)
at com.thankcreate.care.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1794)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1851)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you referring to the same state list from inside your state list drawable?

Comment: Please show the xml file referred to by `drawableId`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by an infinite loop executing. This may be caused by the a circular call in the drawable that is used as your icon. The Drawable with the specified `drawableId` may be calling a second drawable and the second drawable which n turn calls the first one.

Provide more details about the drawable that you are using.That may help in providing better answers.

Comment: In fact , I defined a selector drawable which had a image drawable  resource referenced.Accidently they have the same name and there is no compile error, but it really works in android 4.0. In android 2.3 it will crash. Anyway, thank you very much!